# Marshmallow - validate the sum of attribute in a list of dicts

Tags: python, marshmallow

Lets say this is the json to validate:

```
{
    simulation": [
        {
            "value": 18,
            "frequency": 100
        },
        {
            "value": 19,
            "frequency": 200
        },
        {
            "value": 20,
            "frequency": 500
        },
        {
            "value": 21,
            "frequency": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

How to validate that the sum of all simulation[i]["frequencies"] is equal to 1000?

My problem is, that I already added a validation for each of the dicts in the simulation list:

```
class Simulation(Schema):
    payout_days=fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))
    frequency=fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))

class Main(Schema):
    simulation=fields.Nested(Simulation(many=True))
```

Now I dont know how to make a check over all elements in simulation list, to make sure that the sum of simulation[i]["frequencies"] == 1000. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: this question could do with a python tag?

Comment: @berend thanks, I added a wrong tag, when creating the question. Now it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could use post processor to enforce this validation as shown [in the official documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#raising-errors-in-pre-post-processor-methods) :

```python
from marshmallow import Schema, ValidationError, fields, post_load, validate


class Simulation(Schema):
    value = fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))
    frequency = fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))


class Main(Schema):
    simulation = fields.Nested(Simulation(many=True))

    @post_load
    def validate_frequencies_sum(self, data, **kwargs):
        if sum(sim["frequency"] for sim in data["simulation"]) != 1000:
            raise ValidationError("Sum of frequencies is not 1000")
        return data


d = {
    "simulation": [
        {"value": 18, "frequency": 100},
        {"value": 19, "frequency": 200},
        {"value": 20, "frequency": 500},
        {"value": 21, "frequency": 200},
    ]
}

schema = Main()
schema.load(d)
```